# How to loop through Column A and Paste headers when Column A is Bold

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm new to VBA and I've been trying to crack this for myself but I just can't seem to get it right. I have a sheet with sales data. The macro I am trying to write would loop through a range in column A lets Say "A5:A50" and when a cell is found that contains **Bold** text would paste my headers (let's say in "C6:I6") 2 columns over in that same row.

Here is my attempt-

```
Sub Headers()
Dim Head As Range

For Each Head In Range("A5:A50")
    If Head.Font.Bold = True Then
    Head.Offset(0, 2).Paste ("c6:I6")
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: In the phrase '*when a cell is found that contains Bold text*', the word **contains** is ambiguous. Do you mean that all of the cell's text is bold or some of the celll's text may be bold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to copy the contents of C6:I6 to every row that has a **bold** font applied in column A, you just need to change one line of your code:

```
Sub Headers()
    Dim Head As Range

    For Each Head In Range("A5:A50")
        If Head.Font.Bold = True Then
            'Copy C6:I6 to two columns to the right of current cell
            Range("C6:I6").Copy Head.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

(If you need to also pick up cases where parts of the cell in column A are bold and parts are not, it gets more complicated.  But I suspect you are just wanting the simple approach.)